# Copy local data to hadoop hdfs error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I recently installed/configured hadoop and curently trying to run some tests. My problem is with copying local data to hdfs:

When I try to run

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/develop/test/ test
```

or any similar command, all i get is:

```
copyFromLocal: `test': No such file or directory
```

if I run `ls`, i get the same output:

```
develop@ubuntu:~$ hdfs dfs -ls
ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

I also tried to create the directory `test` with `hdfs dfs -mkdir`, but unsuccessful, what exactly am I missing ?

Comment: try `hdfs dfs -ls /` notice the forward slash. It could be backward slash. I dont remember. Havent worked in HDFS for a while :)

Comment: Make sure you have that "test" file in the given path

Comment: try `hdfs dfs -mkdir /test`

Comment: Thank you all for your input, i have solved the problem, the issue was that /test directory was missing, didn't knew that you need to create it, or use forward slash in hdfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add slash in the HDFS path.

For example,

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /test
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/develop/test/ /test
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a file from your local file system to HDFS, you need to first have that file in your local file system.

Create a file named test under `/home/develop` and then give the path of this file in the command.

You can even use this command too:

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/develop/test test
```

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh Hadoop installation ,you need to create user directory under /user on HDFS .

You are getting this error

```
develop@ubuntu:~$ hdfs dfs -ls
ls: `.': No such file or directory
```

because you do not have any directory /user/develop on HDFS.

You can create user directory with following commands :

```
$> sudo su - hdfs -C "hadoop fs -mkdir /user/develop"
$> sudo su - hdfs -C "hadoop fs -chown -R develop:hadoop /user/develop"
$> sudo su - hdfs -C "hadoop fs -chmod -R 750 /user/develop"
```

You will still need to create `test` directory but if you use you copyFromLocal command then you need to create `test` directory in you HDFS user directory .so absolute path for your `test` dir will be `/user/develop/test` .