# Can't put file from local directory to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-partitioning

I have created a file with name "file.txt" in the local directory , now I want to put it in HDFS by using :-

```
]$ hadoop fs -put file.txt abcd
```

I am getting a response like

```
put: 'abcd': no such file or directory
```

I have never worked on Linux. Please help me out - How do I put the file "file.txt" into HDFS?

Comment: the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738837/copy-local-data-to-hadoop-hdfs-error

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify an absolute path in hadoop (HDFS or wathever other file system used), it will pre-append your **user directory** to create an absloute path.

By default, in HDFS you default folder should be **/user/*user name***.

Then in your case you are trying to create the file `/user/<user name>/abcd` and put inside it the content of your local `file.txt`.

The user name is your operative system user, in your local machine. You can get it using the `whoami` command.

The the problem is that your **user folder** doesn't exist in HDFS, and you need to create it.

BTW, according with hadoop documentation, the correct command to work with HDFS is `hdfs dfs` instead `hadoop fs` (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html). But by now both should work.

Then:

1. If you don't know your user name in your local operative system. Open a terminal and run the `whoami` command.
2. Execute the follow command, replacing your *user name*.

> `hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/<user name>`

And then you should be able to execute your `PUT` command.

NOTE: The `-p` parameter is to create the /user folder if it doesn't exist.